# javascript: How do I add a JSON object with a push()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I hacked this code from somewhere else, but have an object variable to store x,y values in an array every time a hex is clicked, defined with two functions, one to add an element and one to remove the last element

```
var objMoves = {
    length: 0,

    addElem: function addElem(elem) {
        // obj.length is automatically incremented 
        // every time an element is added.
        [].push.call(this, elem);
    },
    removeElem: function removeElem(last) {
        // this removes the last item in the array
        [].splice.call(this,last, 1);
    }

};
```

I call it like this:

```
objMoves.addElem({ x: hexX, y: hexY });
```

Result if I dump the objMoves into the console log is "{"0":{"x":2,"y":1},"length":1}"

However, what I really want is something like

```
objMoves.addElem({ x: hexX, y: hexY },stackID:"abcdef");
```

So the result would be something like

```
{stackId:"abcdef",moves:[{"x":2,"y":1},{"x":3,"y":4}]} 

{stackId:"xyz",moves:[{"x":5,"y":2},{"x":6,"y":2},{"x":7,"y":2}]}
```

etc, where the inner array gets added to for a given `stackID`. I think I need to nest the objects?

Comment: why dont you just define an array property along with "length" and push the element in there?

Comment: Where does the `moves:` property come from?

Comment: You can't use `stackID: "abcdef"` as a function argument. `x: y` notation can only be used in object literals.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @PekosoG Well I would like to do that, what is the syntax? Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar Moves is not defined, but I am just illustrating how I would like it to be stored. I grabbed that code above because it was the only one that worked with "push" that kept a running total of all the previous additions, by using just a "objMoves.push" it seemed to just add the x,y to all indexes in the array. However, I want to be able to add the x,y coordinate to a specific stackId, so I guess there is some nesting going on?

Comment: Andrew Hopkinson, **please read**: [What should you do when someone answers your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

push() is for arrays, not objects, so use the right data structure.

```
 var objMoves = [];
// ...
data[0] = { "": "", "": "" };
data[1] = { ....};
// ...
var tempData = [];
for ( var index=0; index<data.length; index++ ) {
if ( data[index].objMoves ) {
    tempData.push( data );
}
}
 data = tempData;
```

or deal with it like it is an object. while Objects does not support push property,  you can save it as well using the index as key.

Comment: This is not quite what I want to do. I don't want to loop over everything, I want to just add to an array for a specific stackId key inside the objMoves object. Thanks though.

Comment: Hi there, I got it working well, however, I have a function called "drawBoard" that draws the board. I want to loop over all the elements in the object objMoves, but it does not seem to recognize the object, even if I pass it in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is something like this:

```js
var objMoves = {
  addElem: function(id, elem) {
    var obj = this[id] || {
      stackId: id,
      moves: []
    };
    obj.moves.push(elem);
    this[id] = obj;
  },
  removeElem: function(id, last) {
    this[id].moves.splice(last, 1);
  }
}

objMoves.addElem("abcdef", {x: 123, y: 456});
objMoves.addElem("xyz", {x: 1, y: 2});
objMoves.addElem("abcdef", {x: 100, y: 50});
console.log(objMoves);
```

The functions take a stack ID as a parameter, so they can use that as a key into the object to find the sub-object with that ID. The moves are stored in an array in that sub-object.

Comment: That looks like it! I will give it a try, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was a little bit fascinated from the code, that you have taken from the **[MDN JavaScript reference site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Using_an_object_in_an_array-like_fashion)**. It shows us how we could use an object as an array. And so I wrote some functions to do it.

**Solution with all, what you need:**

```js
var objMoves =
{
    // objMoves.length is automatically incremented every time an element is added
    length: 0,
    //add an object to new(with stackId) or given(by stackId) array element
    addElem: function(object, stackId)
    {
        var index = this.getElemIndex(stackId);

        if(index > -1)
            this[index].moves.push(object);
        else
            [].push.call(this, {stackId: stackId, moves: [object]})
    },
    //remove the array element on lastElemIndex
    removeElem: function(lastElemIndex)
    {
        [].splice.call(this, lastElemIndex, 1)
    },
    //remove the object on lastElemIndex from the array element with stackId
    removeMovesElem: function(stackId, lastElemIndex)
    {
        var index = this.getElemIndex(stackId);

        if(index > -1)
            this[index].moves.splice(lastElemIndex, 1)
    },
    //get the array element index by stackId
    getElemIndex: function(stackId)
    {
        for(var i = this.length; i--;)
            if(this[i].stackId == stackId)
                return i
        return -1
    }
};

//we check functions:
objMoves.addElem({x: 2, y: 1}, 'abcdef');
objMoves.addElem({x: 3, y: 4}, 'abcdef');

objMoves.addElem({x: 5, y: 2}, 'xyz');
objMoves.addElem({x: 6, y: 2}, 'xyz');
objMoves.addElem({x: 7, y: 2}, 'xyz');

console.log(JSON.stringify(objMoves, null, '\t'));
console.log('===========================');

var index = objMoves.getElemIndex('abcdef');
objMoves.removeElem(index);
console.log(JSON.stringify(objMoves, null, '\t'));
console.log('===========================');

objMoves.removeMovesElem('xyz', 1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(objMoves, null, '\t'));
```

Comment: The solution from user Barmar is not correct, because he does not put objects on array index. He puts objects to stackId. We can see it in his `console.log` output.